# passing uninitialized character array to function. Crashing

Tags: c, arrays, char

The string lengths are not getting the correct lengths, so the rest of the program doesn't work.  I am trying to read 62 chars per line then print a new line with another 62 chars.

Can anyone help me correctly pass the char arrays to the output function?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE

void output(char *wbuf, char *lbuf, int lineLength);
void readFile(FILE *getty, char *wbuf, char *lbuf);

FILE *getty;

int main(void) {
    char wbuf[1000] = {0}, lbuf[1000] = {0};

    if (fopen_s(&getty,"getty.txt", "r") != 0 ) 
    {
        printf("Failed to open getty.txt for reading.");
    } else {
        readFile(getty, wbuf, lbuf);
    }

    fclose(getty);
    return 0;
}

void readFile(FILE *getty, char *wbuf, char *lbuf) 
{
    static int lineLength = 62;
    while (!feof(getty)) 
    {
        fscanf(getty, "%s", wbuf);
        output(wbuf, lbuf, lineLength);     
    }
}

void output(char *wbuf, char *lbuf, int lineLength) 
{
    int wbufLength, lbufLength, i = 0;

    wbufLength = strlen(wbuf);
    lbufLength = strlen(lbuf);
    //prints incorrect
    printf("wbuflength %d lbuflength %d\n", wbufLength, lbufLength); 
    // lengths
    if ( (wbufLength + lbufLength) <= lineLength) 
    {                  
        strcat(lbuf,wbuf);  //lbuf should be 0 but it starts at
    }                       //274, wbuf not correct either
    else 
    {
        strcat(lbuf,"\n");
        lineLength += 62;
        strcat(lbuf, wbuf);
    }
}
```

Comment: `feof` probably doesn't work like you think it does.

Comment: Pro-tip: Never loop while `feof` returns false, the `EOF` flag will not be set until *after* an I/O operation.

Comment: Also, if you want to get a *line* from a file, there's always [`fgets`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets).

Comment: Another also... Your arrays are *not* uninitialized. You do initialize them in your declaration.

Comment: To check what's going on you might want to run your program in a debugger, and step though the code line by line to see what really happen.

Comment: Ok, feof wasn't working like I thought it should I added a different condition.  It now works, thanks!  Can someone explain to me why feof wasn't working?  I thought it was supposed to exit the loop at the end of the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is your loop condition:

```
while (!feof(getty)) { ... }
```

The EOF flag is not set until *after* an input operation fails.

In your case, the loop loops, then the `fscanf` operation fails because it's at the end of the file but you don't check for that inside the loop, and you then call `output` even though nothing was read from the file. Then the loop continues and *then* it notices that the file have reached EOF.

Comment: An input loop should check the result returned by the input function (`fscanf` in your case). The `feof` function is rarely useful; it can only tell you why you ran out of input after the fact. Recommended reading: Section 12 of the [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://www.c-faq.com/).